# Введение в Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. В общем я хочу познакомится с Spring Framework MVC.. У меня есть знания Java 8, HTML/CSS, XML. Проблема в том, что у меня не такая структура проекта как в уроках. Я хочу использовать чисто аннотации для конфигурирования, ну конечно XML, там где без него никак (конфигурирование Maven). Мне сказали скачать Maven, Tomcat. Все скачал, поставил, переменные прописал и в настройках IntelliJ IDEA 15.1 поставил путь к Maven. Spring MVC скачал как зависимость, (New -> Project... -> Spring -> Spring MVC). Создал.. В итоге у меня такая структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет pom.xml... Я не пойму почему, ведь все подключено и указано. Ну ладно, это поправимо через Add Framework Support -> Maven, и добавляется pom.xml . Но содержимое сильно отличается от того, что в уроках по Spring. 
Пробовал эти уроки: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN66kDMjnYM , вроде без конфигурирования Spring'a через XML, но для меня там все сложно.. Для меня это как темный лес, человек уже сразу на готовом проекте показывает, а я его ещё не создал толком даже. Вот уже два дня сижу и не могу Hello World сделать, везде либо XML, либо у меня что-то в структуре не так (да, по большей части это проблемы с моими руками, наверное). Что я хочу:

1. Что с этим Maven'ом ? Где pox.xml автоматически созданный?
2. Можете кто-то, пожалуйста, скинуть просто Spring MVC веб-приложение
   (типичный Hello World) по самым новым стандартам.. Ну так как сейчас
   пишут на Spring MVC..
3. Есть какие-то уроки, даже пусть на английском (туториалы), где все
   на аннотациях и, как бы сказать, "по-современному", в том тоне, что
   сейчас популярен и востребован. Поделитесь пожалуйста.
4. У меня минимальные знания ВЕБ'а. Правильно ли я понял: На Spring MVC
   мы пишем веб-приложение (сервер), который в свою очередь работает с
   помощью Java сервлетов. Потом страница на HTML/CSS с помощью
   JavaScript обращается к нашему веб-приложению (серверу). На самом
   Spring MVC мы не занимаемся написанием непосредственно страницы
   (HTML/CSS) или все же занимаемся, иначе для чего JSP (а этот
   разновидность HTML). Пролейте свет сюда.

Вопросы не очень грамотные, местами глупые, сразу прошу извинить.

Answer (score 5):

1. Его там не будет. Для того, чтобы он там был, надо создавать **maven-проект** с архетипом spring-mvc (название может быть другим).
2. [Первый результат поисковика по `spring mvc annotation example`](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/)
3. Эти уроки называются [официальная документация](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/). Но она большая, поэтому можешь попробовать [так](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).
4. Вроде да, но нет. Первый делом браузер идет с GET-запросом к серверу, с просьбой дать ему страницу. Тут можно отдать **статическую** страницу (HTML+javascript), а потом через javascript запросить у сервера динамические данные. Либо сгенерировать её при помощи того же JSP, и отдать **сгенерированный** html-контент. Spring как раз таки содержит такую штуку, которая из JSP может сделать HTML. Можно также использовать гибридный подход. Тут дело предпочтения.
5. Изучать spring сразу не стоит точно. Сначала стоит изучить обычные сервлеты.

Comment: Вроде бы все ясно, спасибо. Тогда иду изучать сервлеты, а потом документацию.